# How to handle items inside onListItemClick of ArrayListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to create a list view with names. Clicking on each name will give me different grade.
All names and grades ara taken by a database and stored into json format which is passed through activities with intents:

```
public class StudentList extends ListActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);

/**get the intent*/
Intent studentIntent = getIntent();

/**retrieve the string extra passed*/
ArrayList<String> nameRecd = studentIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
ArrayList<String> gradeRecd = studentIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("grade");
try {
    JSONArray jsonData = new JSONArray(getIntent().getStringExtra("data"));
    Log.i("json review:", "Check out my JSON, looks like his JMother");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameRecd);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
int pos = position;

Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected" + "Grade:"  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

So I want for every selected name to be able to toast or handle otherwise tha grade of the same position so I can build some kind of profile for the specific student and be able to access it by clicking on students name!

Comment: I don't get what is your exact problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved starting the sameintent inside onListItemClick...

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

/**get the intent*/
Intent studentIntent = getIntent();

/**retrieve the data extra passed*/
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> grades = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject();
try {
    JSONArray jARR = new JSONArray(getIntent().getStringExtra("data"));
    Log.i("json review:", "Check out my JSON, looks like his JMother");
    for(int i=0;i<jARR.length();i++){
        json_data = jARR.getJSONObject(i);
        names.add((json_data.getString("name"))) ;
        grades.add((json_data.getString("grade"))) ;

    }



} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```